# OpenSUSE snapshots not allowing ssh

Tags: ssh, google-compute-engine, opensuse

I can't seem to ssh into any instances that are created from a snapshot of an openSUSE instance that's created within Google Cloud (ie: not from a snapshot created locally and then uploaded). I've tested this with three different openSUSE instances, 2 that I had been working on and one that I created only to test this on, and none have been able to produce snapshots that produce instances that allow ssh. To be clear, the instances created from the snapshots start up perfectly fine and show no issues from the console, but neither the console's built in ssh nor any other ssh client (putty, mobaxterm) gets anything more than a time out error. I have successfully created instances from both a Windows and Debian snapshots that I have created myself, so I'm confident it's an issue with the specific OS.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create an instance based off of the openSUSE image
2. Create a snapshot based off of the instance you just created
3. Create an instance based off of the snapshot you just created
4. Attempt, and fail, to connect to the instance via ssh

Any help with this would be much appreciated, and thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce your issue. I'll report it to Google. If your run the command

```
gcloud compute instances get-serial-port-output <your-new-instance>
```

You will notice that there's an error indicating that couldn't find the disk.

Comment: This issue has been reported to Google

Comment: Internal bug ref is 18961371

Answer (score 0):

SUSE has fixed the issue yesterday on `SLES` distros. The following new images are now available (bug-exempt):

- `sles-11-sp3-v20150310`
- `sles-12-v20150310`

We are still working on a fix to `openSUSE`, and we still don't have a fix for *existing* instances.

Answer (score 0):

A procedure to address running instances has been posted:

https://forums.suse.com/showthread.php?6142-Image-from-snapshot-will-not-boot&p=26957#post26957

The above post contains all the details, the procedure below addresses the question about "what to do with running instances."

**SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 SP3 (sles-11-sp3)**
1.) Edit /etc/sysconfig/bootloader
In the "DEFAULT_APPEND" assignment replace "root=/dev/disk/by-id.." with "root=/dev/sda1". Reform the same substitution for the "FAILSAFE_APPEND" assignment.
Add NON_PERSISTENT_DEVICE_NAMES=1 to the end of the line, after "quiet"

2.) Edit /etc/fstab
Replace "/dev/disk/by-id..." with "/dev/sda1"

3.) Edit /boot/menu.lst
Replace "root=/dev/disk/by-id.." with "root=/dev/sda1" and "disk=/dev/disk/by-id/..." with "disk=/dev/sda" in both options.
Add NON_PERSISTENT_DEVICE_NAMES=1 to the end of the line starting with "kernel"

4.) Reboot the instance

5.) Execute mkinitrd

6.) Edit /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules (if it exists)
Remove the mac address condition, "ATTR{address}==.....", from the rules.

**SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 (sles-12)**
1.) Edit /etc/sysconfig/bootloader
In the "DEFAULT_APPEND" assignment replace "root=/dev/disk/by-id.." with "root=/dev/sda1" and "disk=/dev/disk/by-id/..." with "disk=/dev/sda". Perform the same substitution for the "FAILSAFE_APPEND" assignment.
Add NON_PERSISTENT_DEVICE_NAMES=1 to the end of the line, after "quiet"

2.) Edit /etc/fstab
Replace "/dev/disk/by-id..." with "/dev/sda1"

3.) Edit /etc/default/grub
In the "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT" assignment replace "root=/dev/disk/by-id.." with "root=/dev/sda1" and "disk=/dev/disk/by-id/..." with "disk=/dev/sda".
Add NON_PERSISTENT_DEVICE_NAMES=1 to the end of the line, after "quiet"

4.) Create a new grub configuration (SLES 12)
export GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true
grub2-mkconfig > /boot/grub2/grub.cfg

5.) Execute mkinitrd

6.) Edit /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules (if it exists)
Remove the mac address condition, "ATTR{address}==.....", from the rules.

Answer (score 0):

A new openSUSE 13.2 image has been published that addresses the issue as well. New instances started from opensuse-13-2-v20150315 will work with no issues with the snapshot feature in GCE. For running instances use the process outlined for SUSE Linux Enterprise 12, that should work. I did not test the procedure on openSUSE.